(APA) How to cite same author, but one has n.d. and the other has a date
I have two sources that are from the same webpage, but I am citing different articles from the same webpage. The problem I have is, one article has a date, while the other doesn't.
For example:
National Coalition for Sexual Freedom inc. (2023) Coalition partner
National Coalition for Sexual Freedom inc. (n.d.). What professionals
I would initially obviously think (with following the typical alphabetical rules) that the coalition one would be placed first. But I've seen different sources talk about placing earlier works first, forgetting about the alphabetical rule and I wasn't sure how true that was. With the second one not having a date does that impact the citing at all, or should I ignore it and continue with citing it alphabetically by the webpage's title ("coalition partner" being placed before "what professionals")
Thank you!

Quick answer is alphabetical by author first and then chronological, with dates going first, then in press, then no date (or so I believe). However, I would highly suggest using referencing software for a few reasons:

Formatting issues, as you are experiencing, are not a thing. Your references have their information gathered by DOI (or similar) and are added to the document in whatever format you select.

Reformatting issues are also not a thing. You've not indicated what you are writing for. But if it's for a journal then you should consider that it may be rejected and the next journal you submit to could have different formatting style. That's the difference between three clicks of a mouse if using referencing software verses hours of manual reformatting.

Future use. For me, the greatest advantage of using referencing software is you can organise your references into groups based on anything, and then all relevant references are easily to hand when you next need them, saving time searching folders or the internet for something you have already.


Bare in mind though, that the order of references will have little to no effect on either chances of publication or grade, depending on what this is for. Your stressing about the order of references is probably having a far greater effect.
Hope this helps.
